# Lightning CTI saveLog Date and Number Formats

Tags: javascript, lightning, cti

I'm having trouble saving the ActivityDate and the CallDurationInSeconds via the saveLog call from the Lightning Open CTI API.  I have tried many formats for the date, string with the date, string with the date and time, with a T separator, with a space seperator, with a new Date() object.  All give the same error like so: *Due Date Only: value not of required type: 2017-05-17T15:33:08*

I have the same problem with the CallDurationinSeconds.  I tried as a number and as a string of a number, both fail with an error like: *Call Duration: value not of required type: 50*

Some examples of what I tried.

```
sforce.opencti.saveLog({value: {entityApiName: 'Task',Status : 'Pending',Type :'Phone Call',Priority : 'Normal', CallDisposition:'Good Call', ActivityDate : '2017-05-17T15:33:08',Subject : 'Call',Description : 'Test', WhatId: accountID},callback: SaveLogCallback });

sforce.opencti.saveLog({value: {entityApiName: 'Task',Status : 'Pending',Type :'Phone Call',Priority : 'Normal', CallDisposition:'Good Call', ActivityDate : '2017-05-17',Subject : 'Call',Description : 'Test', WhatId: accountID},callback: SaveLogCallback });

sforce.opencti.saveLog({value: {entityApiName: 'Task',Status : 'Pending',Type :'Phone Call',Priority : 'Normal', CallDisposition:'Good Call', ActivityDate : new Date(),Subject : 'Call',Description : 'Test', WhatId: accountID},callback: SaveLogCallback });

sforce.opencti.saveLog({value: {entityApiName: 'Task',Status : 'Pending',Type :'Phone Call',Priority : 'Normal', CallDisposition:'Good Call', CallDurationInSeconds: 50, Subject : 'Call',Description : 'Test', WhatId: accountID},callback: SaveLogCallback });

sforce.opencti.saveLog({value: {entityApiName: 'Task',Status : 'Pending',Type :'Phone Call',Priority : 'Normal', CallDisposition:'Good Call', CallDurationInSeconds: '50', Subject : 'Call',Description : 'Test', WhatId: accountID},callback: SaveLogCallback });
```

Any help you might have is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We've confirmed this is a bug on Salesforce's side and published a Known Issues article

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008mFpQAI

You can click 'This Issue Affects Me' to follow the article and be notified when the fix is released for your instance.